# if $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Tags: probability-theory

I know there is theorem saying that for any measurable function $g$ and $h$, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $g(X)$ and $h(Y)$ are also independent.
If I let $g(x) = h(x)= \sqrt{x}$, can I say that if $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

I think this is incorrect because it depends on the sign of the set $A$ and $B$ in $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $X$ be a coin flip, $-1$ or $1$. Let $Y$ be the opposite. Then $X^2=Y^2=1$ and are independent but $X$ and $Y$ aren't.

Why this doesn't contradict what you know: $\sqrt{X^2}=|X|=1=|Y|=\sqrt{Y^2}$.