# Can we find an example that $X^2$ and $Y^2$ independent, but $X$ is not independent of $Y$?

Tags: probability

Following this question: [if $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1971863/if-x2-and-y2-are-independent-then-x-and-y-are-independent).

Can we find an example that $X^2$ and $Y^2$ independent, but $X$ is not independent of $Y$?

---

I am confused about the answer. Here we take $P(X=-1)=p=1-P(X=1)$, but what dose that mean "Let Y
be the opposite$?

Comment: It means $Y=-X$.

Comment: It means whenever $X=1, Y=-1$, and whenever $X=-1, Y=1$.

Comment: Here is a similar example: Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, and $\varepsilon$ is a Bernoulli($\pm1,\,1/2)$ random variable independent of $(X,Y)$.  Define $X_1=\varepsilon X$ and $X_2=-\varepsilon Y$.
\begin{align}
E[e^{i(tX_1+sX_2)}]&=\operatorname{Re}\Big(E[e^{itX}]E[e^{-isY}]\big)
\end{align}and\begin{align}
E[e^{itX_1}]E[e^{isX_2}]&=\operatorname{Re}\big(E[e^{itX}]\big)\operatorname{Re}\big(E[e^{isY}]\big)
\end{align}Thus, in general $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not independent. However, as
$X_1^2=X^2$ and $X_2^2=Y^2$, we have  $X^2_1$ and $X^2_2$ are independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest example is when $X=Y$, and $\mathbb{P}(X=\pm 1)=\frac 12$.
Then
$$
\mathbb{P}(X=1,Y=1)=\mathbb{P}(X=1)=\frac12\neq \frac14 =\mathbb{P}(X=1)\mathbb{P}(Y=1)
$$
and at the same time $X^2\equiv 1$, $Y^2\equiv 1$, and a constant random variable is independent of any other one (if $X\equiv c$ then $\mathbb{P}(X\in A,Y\in B)=1_{\{c\in A\}}\mathbb{P}(Y\in B)=\mathbb{P}(X\in A)\cdot \mathbb{P}(Y\in B)$ as required).